# Unable to "check" dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: android, arraylist, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm trying to make **dynamically** created checkboxes depending on the item selected in my 'color' spinner.

For example:  if I select **"red"** on my spinner, the following checkboxes will be created:  **Apple [ ],  Strawberry [ ],  Cherry [ ]**.  If I select **"yellow"** from teh spinner, the following checkboxes will be created:  **Banana  [ ],  Pineapple  [ ]**.

My code works and displays the listed items correctly when I run it but why are my dynamically generated checkboxes **"uncheckable"** when I press on them?  The little "checkmark" doesn't appear in the boxes at all.

```
private Fruits fruit = new Fruits();

final GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp);

sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long l){

      String item = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
      List<String> myList = fruit.getFruits(item);

      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity_1.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, myList);
      gv.setAdapter(adapter_1);
   }
```

EDIT:

I'm using a `Fruits` java class to generate my checkbox items:

```
public class Fruits {
   List<String> getFruits(String colour) {
      List<String> fruit = new ArrayList<String>();

      if (colour.equals("red")) {
          fruit.add("Apple");
          fruit.add("Strawberry");
          fruit.add("Cherry");
      }
      else if (colour.equals("yellow") {
          fruit.add("Banana");
          fruit.add("Pineapple");
      }

      return fruit;

   }
}
```

I'm not using a string.xml file to fill my checkbox items.

Comment: I might be missing something, but it looks like you're creating a list of strings and not Checkboxes.
Where do you dynamically create the checkboxes?

Comment: Ah, I'm not really sure tbh.  I'm just starting out with Android programming.  Do I do something like:  `CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();` inside `onItemSelected`?

Comment: In general yes something like that.
It's been a while since I did Android work and I'm not next to my work station to check it.
But in general you need to create the new View, in this case the CheckBox and then add it to Whichever View you want, for example the GridView.
Then it should work

Comment: It would have been easier to guide if you had attached your xml file too.

Comment: I'm actually using a Java class called `Fruits` (hence I instantiated it at the very top).  And in that Fruits java class is just simple if-else statements like `if(fruit.equals("red")) { fruit.add("Apple") }`

Answer (score 1):

To make a checkbox selected you need add setChecked.Inside your onItemSelected add this code to make it selected

```
checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

Also in your code I think there is no dynamic creation of check box.If you want to create check box dynamically then create like this

```
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
checkboxsetText("created new checkbox");
```

Comment: How would I pass the text value of the checked boxes to my next Activity?

Comment: whenever something is clicked pass the list item of that position to next activity